# Is every curl-free $L^1$ vector field locally a gradient, in the weak sense?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde, curl

Let $\Omega$ be an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $E$ be a $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ vector field on $\Omega$. We say that $E$ is curl-free in the weak sense if $E$ is a weak solution to $\nabla \times E = 0$. In other words, for any scalar test function $\psi \in C_c(\Omega)$, we have

$$
\int_\Omega E \times \nabla \psi = 0
$$

Let $p \in \Omega$. Does there exist some neighborhood $U$ of $p$ and some $L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$ scalar function $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla f = E$ in the weak sense?

Recall that $\nabla f = E$ in the weak sense if and only if for any test function $\psi \in C_c(U)$, we have

$$
\int_U E \cdot \nabla \psi = \int_U f \psi
$$

---

I've been able to prove this when $E$ is an $L^p_{\mathrm{loc}}$ vector field, $p > 3$, but nothing with less regularity. In case it is useful, I'll put a sketch of that proof below.

For simplicity, let $\Omega$ be a ball of radius 1 and center 0. If $E$ is smooth curl-free vector field on $\Omega$, then we can define $f(x)$ as the line integral of $E$ over any line $h(t)$ connecting $0$ to $x$. This is well-defined because $E$ is curl-free and $\Omega$ is simply connected. Furthermore, $\nabla f = E$. We can bound $|f(x) - f(0)|$ by parameterizing this line $h(t)$ by two variables $(\alpha, \beta)$ where $0 \leq \alpha \leq 1$ and $0 \leq \beta \leq 1$ and use the integral

$$
f(x) - f(0) = \int E(h(t, \alpha, \beta)) \cdot \frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t, \alpha, \beta) \mathrm{d}t \mathrm{d}\alpha \mathrm{d}\beta
$$

This integral is bounded by some multiple of the $L^p$ norm of $E$. The details get a bit hairy, but the important thing is that $|f| \ll \|E\|_{L^p}$.

Now given an arbitrary $L^p$ vector field $E$, approximate $E$ by smooth vector fields $E_m = E * \eta_m$ where $\eta_m$ is a smooth mollifier (i.e. ``approximate identity''). Let $f_m$ be the solution to $\nabla f_m = E_m$ defined above. Because $E_m$ converges in the $L^p$ norm, $f_m$ will converge uniformly. The limit of $f_m$ is some continuous function $f$ such that $\nabla f = E$, in the weak sense.

Comment: +1, but why is this your definition of a weak solution to $\nabla\times E=0$? 
$$ \int \nabla \times E \cdot F = \int \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j E_k F_i =  - \int \epsilon_{ijk} E_k \partial_j F_i$$ and then $-\epsilon_{ijk} = - \epsilon_{kij} = \epsilon_{kji}$ which gives $ \int \nabla \times E \cdot F =  \int  E \cdot \nabla \times F$

Comment: I had a quick look at the contents of Galdi's book (so I could have missed it) and couldn't find anything directly about curls. But presumably there is a link to the Helmholtz decomposition which holds in e.g. $L^2$. If you formulate the weak curl as in my above comment then i think the answer is positive in $L^2$, since on the test function side we have that divergence-free iff is a curl, so $\int\nabla\times E\cdot F=0$ iff $\int E\cdot H$ for all div-free $H$, and then Thm III.1.1 says that you are a weak gradient of some $H^2$ function. There's something for other p too..

Comment: The two definitions are equivalent of vanishing curl are equivalent. My derivation was
$$ 0 = \int (\nabla \times E \psi)_i = \int \epsilon_{ijk} \partial_j E_k \psi = - \int \epsilon_{ijk} E_k \partial_j \psi = - \int E \times \nabla \psi $$

Comment: The Helmotz decomposition is actually what started me down this rabbit hole, but I haven't learned about the $L^2$ solution. Do you know if the Helmotz condition works for locally $L^2$ functions too (that is, $L^2$ on bounded sets)?

Comment: Actually, I'm only asking about local solutions, so that's not an issue. That seems to prove the case for $L^2_{\mathrm{loc}}$ vector fields, nice! I'm still curious about functions with less regularity, too

Comment: (obvious typo in my prior comment, weak gradient of some $H^1$.) yeah it works on i think any domain for $L^2$ and there seems to be some fussing about for $p\in(1,\infty)$ that I don't understand. This is [Galdi's book](https://zbmath.org/?q=an%3A1245.35002) that I was referring to